# JPA One To Many relation results

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, one-to-many, relation

i am working on a personnal project and i have a little problem with JPA.

The thing is i have an user class and each user have multiple image so i wrote the class this way :

```
@Entity

public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

.
.
.
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID")
private Set<Image> imageList;
```

that create a join column in the Image table as expected. Now i want to retrive all the images from a User with this code:

```
public  Set<Image> retriveImage(User u) {
    User user =em.find(User.class, u.getId());
    return user.getImageList();

}
```

I am facing a problem after that : i try to upload 2 images, let's say img1 and img2 and retrieve them but sometimes i get a set with img1 and img1, i refresh the page and i get another set with img2 and img2, sometimes with img1 and img2 etc... I mean the order is never the same and sometimes, all the results are not in it, why ?

I tried doing it with a query with this code:

```
public List<Image> retriveImage(User u) {
    TypedQuery<Image> q = em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.OWNER_ID=:id",Image.class);
    q.setParameter("id", u.getId());

    return q.getResultList();

}
```

but i have an error saying "OWNERD_ID" is not a valid type ( because the field is only in the DB, not in the image class ), can i get it working with query ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You use field names in JPQL, not column names. Does Image have the User id field?

Comment: The order is never the same because  you have not specified any ordering.

Comment: Let's say that Image has a attribute userId mapped to owner_id. The JPQL should be:    
`SELECT i FROM Image i WHERE i.userId=:id`  
Furthermore, the result is not ordered as you expected.  
  
It's very wierd that the query is returned duplicated and unpredictable registries in this kind of relationship. It's a good idea to enable hibernate query logging.  
  
`<property name="show_sql">true</property>`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i had no field userId i added one and it works, but in the third example of the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html they don't do anything in the order class... Now they are ordered well thanks to the SQL request